# A Polynomial that Passes through the following four points?

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots, interpolation

I'm trying to do this for practice but I'm just going nowhere with it, I'd love to see some work and answers on it.

Thanks :)

Find a polynomial that passes through the points (-2,-1), (-1,7), (2,-5), (3,-1). Present the answer in standard form.

What I've tried:

[image: What I firstly tried but went nowhere]

[image: Another attempt to get somewhere]

Comment: Thanks for telling me.

I put some pictures up of what I've tried, spent so much time thinking about this and got no where.

Comment: You made your work harder by putting the constants inside the powers, and not recognizing that you have a system of linear equations in $a^3, b^2, c, d$.... Try $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d$$
\begin{eqnarray*} 
-1 &=& a (-2)^3 + b(-2)^2 + c(-2) + d \\
 7 &=& a (-1)^3 + b(-1)^2 + c(-1) + d \\
-5 &=& a(2)^3 + b (2)^2 + c (2) + d \\
-1 &=& a(3)^3 + b(3)^2 + c (3) + d
\end{eqnarray*}
or 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
-8 a  + 4b -2c + d &=&  -1\\
-{\ }a{\ } +{\ } b -{\ } c + d &=&{\ } 7 \\
 8a + 4b  + 2c  + d&=&-5 \\
27a + 9b + 3c + d&=&-1
\end{eqnarray*}
with solution
\begin{eqnarray*} 
a&=&{\ }{\ }1\\
b&=&-2\\
c&=&-5\\
d&=&{\ }{\ }5
\end{eqnarray*}
and so $f(x) = x^3 -2x^2-5x+5$

Comment: Thank for the reply, but I don't quite understand how you got  to the solution from when you subbed in (x,y) into f(x)=ax3+bx2+cx+d

Comment: Aha. $ax^3$ means first cube $x$ then multiply by $a$, not the other way around. So $(-2)$ subbed for $x$ in $ax^3$ is $a\cdot (-2)^3= a\cdot (-8) = -8 a$. Same for the other terms and subs.

Comment: alright thanks again that makes sense, but when you got the equations such as −8a+4b−2c+d = -1, how were you able to get the solution, find out what a,b,c,d was? :)

Comment: I used Mathematica. You can too use a computer algebra system (free, online or school-commercial) to at least verify the results. However, I think it is useful to  do some calculations by hand, to get a feel for the algorithms for solving systems of linear equations.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

Way 1: Consider the polynomial
$$\small A(x+1)(x-2)(x-3)+B(x+2)(x-2)(x-3)+C(x+2)(x+1)(x-3)+D(x+2)(x+1)(x-2).$$
You can find constants $A,B,C,D$ such that the above polynomial will do the job. For example, to make the polynomial be equal to $-1$ at $-2$, all we need to do is to make $A(-2+1)(-2+-2)(-2+-3)=1$.

The hard thing about this procedure is presenting the answer in standard form. That is a routine but very unpleasant calculation.

Way 2: Let our polynomial be $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$.  Because the curve $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$  passes through $(-2,-1)$ we have
$$-8a+4b-2c+d=-1.$$
Similarly, we obtain three other linear equations in $4$ unknowns. It akes a fair amount of routine work, but you can solve the resulting system of $4$ linear equations in $4$  unknowns, and then you are finished.

Comment: i tried doing your second way, but I don't know the way to solve the resulting system. Any advice or demonstration?

Comment: A $4\times 4$ system is never fun. You can easily eliminate $d$ and get a $3\times 3$. And this type of system (Vandemonde type) has been much studied, there are shortcuts. However, that would introduce more theory than is expected of you.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** List the equations that define the function according to ax<sup>3</sup> + bx<sup>2</sup> + cx + d:

```
-8a+ 4b - 2c + d = -1 (equation1)

-1a + 1b + -1c + d = 7 (equation2) 

8a + 4b + 2c + d = -5 (equation3) 

27a + 9b + 3c + d = -1 (equation4)
```

**Step 2 :** Use matrix operations to simplify the system of equations
for example: add/subtract multiples of equation1 from/to each of the equations below it to remove the a's from them.

Then add/subtract multiples of the **new** equation2 from/to the equations below it to remove the b's from them. .

Then add/subtract multiples of the **new** equation3 from/to the equations below it (which is only equation 4) to remove the c's from it.

After completing this process, the system of equations will be easy to solve since equation4 will end up having 1 variable (which will be d), which you can calculate and substitute in equation3 to get c and then substitute d and c into equation2 and so on

Comment: why do you write $8a + 2b + 2c + d = -5\,\,$ ?

Comment: miscalculation. it should be 8a + 4b + 2c + d. changed it now